# Using multiple languages in asp.net mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to provide user an option to change the UI language of my asp.net mvc website. I am planning to offer 2 languages to the user ie : English and Dutch

For that I edited my web.config file and added :

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

Now I added 2 files `Resources.resx` (the default file) and `Resources.nl-NL.resx` (the resource file for dutch).

I am referring to the Resources file from my view as `<title>@WebApplication9.App_GlobalResources.Resources.RequestTitle</title>`.

When the language is changed, I am changing the Culture like this :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
```

But even after the language change to dutch and changing the culture values to the ones specified above, the English value from `Resources.resx` is always show instead of getting the value from `Resources.nl-NL.resx`.

Could you please help me to find out what I am missing here?

Comment: Just a hunch ... try renaming the Resource File to `Resources.nl.resx`

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider : I tried that initially itself, but did not work.

Comment: An initial level troubleshooting proved that when I changed the language in browser, the UI language is changing. So the problem is obviously with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");` and/or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");` I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by setting the culture for the current each time while a controller action method is called. 
The issue is caused since when I change the culture, it is set for current thread only. When user requests for another view, the thread might be different. So I need to set the Culture for each new request/new thread.

I give the user to have only 2 languages ie English(en-US) and Dutch(nl-NL). So I created 2 resx files with names `Resources.resx` for English and `Resources.nl.resx` for Dutch. When user changes the current language I keep the language in Session and stores in database for remembering it during further logins.

```
if(selectedLang == Dutch)
{
    Session["Language"] = "nl-NL";
}
else
{
    Session["Language"] = "en-US";
}
```

Now the `Session["Language"]` holds the user's preferred language. Now in each controller action method :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActionMethodName(DataClass dataObj)
{
    Sessions.ChangeLanguage(Session["Language"].ToString());
}
```

`Sessions.ChangeLanguage(string language)` is a static method in a class `Sessions` as below :

```
public static void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
}
```

Comment: But doesn't setting the CurrentCulture change the language for all sessions not just the current user?

Comment: @userSteve: No it is for the current users session only

Answer (score 0):

This might help;

Your POST method:

```
public ActionResult SetCultureToNL()
    {
        SetCulture("nl-BE");

        return View("index");
    }

private void SetCulture(String culture)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        if (httpContext.Request.Cookies["_Culture"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cultureCookie = new HttpCookie("_Culture", culture);

            httpContext.Response.SetCookie(cultureCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("_Culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;

            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

And a GET method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string cultureName = GetCultureCookieValue(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context);

            // Modify current thread's cultures            
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
      // ...
   }

public static String GetCultureCookieValue(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies["_Culture"];

        if (cultureCookie != null)
        {
            return CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureCookie.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(httpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]); // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages
        }
    }
```

Comment: When are we supposed to call the `POST` ?

Comment: When u r setting the culture