# Why does POST request to controller not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is a POST request on login page which, for some reason, doesn't work. Code for the request is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post(path, {param: "val"});
});
```

The method for getting this POST and working around it is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Func(string val)
{
    ... //some stuff happening
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Basically a standard method. Thing is, the method isn't called (most of the times) when I'm sending this POST from login page. However, when I log in and try to send it, the method works as intended. So is there any connection between sending POST request and being authorised?

Edit: as I got another question (kinda related to this one), should I post it here or create a new question?

Comment: Do you have any other filters on your `ActionResult` method or your `Controller` class?

Comment: Only ```HttpPost``` on ```ActionResult``` and ```HandleError``` on controller.

Comment: Can you show us how you are sending your `POST` data to your `Controller` method?

Comment: To be more precise, it's like this:
```$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post("/Controller/Func", {val: "value"});
});```
Or do I miss the point?

Comment: I meant on which event are you `POST`ing your data? Is it a button click? Seems that you are sending the data when the document is loaded which is not correct. You can either put your data in a `form` and then `submit` it to the `Controller` OR you can bind the event on a click and the send it your method.

Comment: You're right, I'm trying to send the post right after the document is loaded. Thing is, I wanted the code in controller to be executed even before the page is loaded, if that is possible at all. Can you please tell me why it's not correct to send data with (document).ready?

Comment: In MVC- the `Controller` renders your `View` so anything that you want beforehand should be handled at the `Controller` level before you render your `View`. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve until I can see your entire code. Why do you want to `post` something on `document.ready` with a certain value. Where is this value coming from? Is it a hard coded value? If so, then get your data before your render your view.

Comment: I'm trying to get the language of user's browser and set the site's language to that. ```var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;``` — the way I get the parameter to send.

Comment: Okay, you can see this answer for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654176/using-multiple-languages-in-asp-net-mvc-website

Comment: you have to show the code  that is sending  POST from login page.  And pls show the real action with real parameters if you want the real help.

Comment: ```<script type="text/javascript">  $(document).ready(function () {
        var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
            $.post("/Account/SetLang", {lang: lang});
        });
    </script>```
I'm sorry it's hard to read — I don't know how to make it readable in comments.

Answer (score 1):

you have a bug in you login script

replace

```
$.post("/Account/SetLang", {lang: lang});
```

with

```
$.post("/Account/SetLang", {val: lang});
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. Still, the post doesn't call the method. So the thing in question is why doesn't POST work? And only on login page, too.

Answer (score 0):

> when I log in and try to send it, the method works as intended.

Sounds like you have an `Authorize` filter on your method or controller.

Authorization filters can be applied to actionresults or controllers to only allow logged-in users to access those endpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorization-filters

Comment: Controller has only ```[HandleError]``` filter, the method I use has only ```[HttpPost]``` filter, no others.