# How to send POST request from login page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a html select for switching languages on the site.

```
<div class= "langselect">
    <select id ="select" onchange="changeLang()">
            <option disabled selected><%: GlobalInterpreter.GetTranslate("Shared", "Language") %></option>
            <option value="en"><%: GlobalInterpreter.GetTranslate("Shared", "English") %></option>
            <option value="ru"><%: GlobalInterpreter.GetTranslate("Shared", "Russian") %></option>
            <option value="es"><%: GlobalInterpreter.GetTranslate("Shared", "Spanish") %></option>
            <option value="fr"><%: GlobalInterpreter.GetTranslate("Shared", "French") %></option>
        </select>
</div>
```

And here's js code for changing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeLang () {
        element = document.querySelector('#select');
        console.log(element.value);

        $.post("<%:Url.Action("SetLang", "Account")%>", { lang: element.value });
        location.reload();
        };
</script>
```

Controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetLang(string lang)
        {
            ...user_lang = lang;
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

So the problem is the same as it was in my previous question ([Why does POST request to controller not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108907/why-does-post-request-to-controller-not-work)) — the method is not called when I send POST from login page. So now I'm not trying to work with data before page is loaded, I'm just trying to change site language on the login page according to user's choice. What can be the problem with POST? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the problem is the same, why create a new question? That means it's a duplicate question and should be closed. Instead, you should update your original question if you have more details to add.

Comment: A quick look at [`jQuery.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) suggest you're calling `location.reload()` too early. You should reload the page *inside* the `success` callback function.

Comment: I asked about editing in prev question, didn't get the answer, so created a new question, thinking that's ok. Noted for the future.
As for the code — I put reload into success, but POST doesn't work at all. So the page is not reloading, uh, nothing happens. Moreover, on other pages of the site language changes as intended, but the page is not reloaded at all.

Comment: Did you try debugging to see that your JavaScript code is actually running? And that `<%:Url.Action("SetLang", "Account")%>` shows the URL you expect? Since it seems in the other question to be difficult to find the problem from the information you've given, I suggest you create a [mre]. E.g. a *small* GitHub repository that reproduces the problem and **link to it**.